# How to calculate gradients for a neural network with theano when using Q-Learning

Tags: neural-network, theano, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use a standard fully-connected neural net as the basis for action values in Q-Learning.  I am using http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html#mlp as a reference specifically this line:

```
gparams = [T.grad(cost, param) for param in classifier.params]
```

I would like to calculate the error for my output unit associated with the last action using the Q-Learning policy control method (as described in http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node65.html) and set the other output errors to zero.

How can I use Theano's grad function to back-propagate the errors to the rest of the neural network?

Comment: I don't have experience with applying reinforcement learning along with supervised learning; but if you can define your q-learning stuff with Theano expressions and make them part of computational graph, then you can just back-propagate errors the normal way (i.e using T.grad(..) ). This might be a bit relevant:
https://github.com/spragunr/deep_q_rl

Comment: Yes, I saw this project and am using it as a reference.  It seems the grad function already does the work for me if I calculate a loss using just the selected action.

Answer (score 0):

Neural nets are just one possible way of parametrizing your Q-function. The way you perform gradient descent in this case is explained in this [section](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node87.html) of Sutton and Barto's book. Just treat the weights of your neural net as a vector of parameters.